# How to direct localhost to mystorefront in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Now when I go to `https://localhost:9002/` it opens `hac (hybris admin console).`

When I go to `https://powertools.local:9002/nystorefront/powertools/en/USD/cart` I can reach **my storefront**.

I want to reach `mystore` when I go to `localhost:9002`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure webroot and storefrontContextRoot in local.properties file.

1) Add properties to your config/local.properties, change `mystorefront` (mystorefront.webroot) with your storefront name. Also, need to change hac webroot to `/hac`

```
hac.webroot=/hac  

mystorefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```

2) To open your site without passing query parameter(?site=mysite), run the below Impex. Change `mysite` with your CMSSite name. This will also resolve your error(**Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL**).

```
$siteUid=mysite       

# CMS Site                                                                                                 
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite ; uid[unique=true] ; urlPatterns                                                                                                                  ;      
                      ; $siteUid         ; (?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=$siteUid)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://$siteUid\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://[^/].*$ ;
```

Comment: I went to localhost:9002/hac/console/impex/import and imported that script. Used mystorefront instead of mysite. I tried to go to localhost:9002 after ant clean all but console now shows no error , only web shows server error . can not connect. then used my instead of mysite .  it says `WARN [hybrisHTTP7] [DefaultCMSSiteService] More than one site associated with URL [https://localhost:9002]. Returning first.` because it is powertools, i should include also `powertools`?

Comment: Goto HMC/back office > cmssite > remove site "mystorefront'

Comment: There you will find another OOTB site, use that name in impex. You don't have to rebuild your server.

Comment: I went to hcms- websites

`mysite
true
[]
 
powertools
Powertools Site
false (i made this false)
Powertools Content Catalog
 
electronics
Electronics Site
true
Electronics Content Catalog
 
apparel-de
Apparel Site DE
true
Apparel DE Content Catalog
 
apparel-uk
Apparel Site UK
true
Apparel UK Content Catalog`


@HybrisFreelance now localhost can not be opened. and no log on console.

Comment: can this be about this part of localproperties 

`
#website.powertools.http=http://powertools.local:9001/mystorefront
#website.powertools.https=https://powertools.local:9002/mystorefront(i disabled because i dont need that. i need to direct this to mystore)

website.mystore.http=http://localhost:9001
website.mystore.https=https://localhost:9002`

in past , this was opening https://localhost:9002/powertools/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Measuring-%26-Layout-Tools/c/1358

but i want to go to https://localhost:9002/mystore/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Measuring-%26-Layout-Tools/c/1358

Comment: how can i contact, still continues

Comment: Drop me an email at contact@helphybris.com

Answer (score 4):

I will assume your web extension name is ***mystorefront***.

Add these into your config/local.properties

```
# This way hac extension will be available on https://localhost:9002/hac instead of https://localhost:9002/
hac.webroot=/hac  


# If you want to remap the context path to the root site on the web container
# then you must set these values to be blank, do not set them to be '/'
mystorefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```

Also make sure that the urlPatterns associated with your CMSSite allow you to access your storefront via: https://localhost:9002/

You can also find this properties and additional information in your **mystorefront**/project.properties.
As already mentioned there, "If you want to change these values then it is suggested that you override both 
of them in your config/local.properties file rather than changing the value here".

Comment: Have you added the "hac.webroot=/hac " as well ?

Comment: yes now it says `
WARN  [hybrisHTTP7] [ContextInformationLoader] Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL (https://localhost:9002)!`

Comment: This is because of the urlPatterns of the CMSSite which most probably contain mystorefront within

Comment: Search the instance of your CMSSite and update it's urlPatterns attribute so that your extension will be accessible via https://localhost:9002

Comment: @user9708984 find my answer to resolve your error (Cannot find CMSSite associated ..)

Comment: can this be about this part of localproperties 

`
#website.powertools.http=http://powertools.local:9001/mystorefront
#website.powertools.https=https://powertools.local:9002/mystorefront(i disabled because i dont need that. i need to direct this to mystore)

website.mystore.http=http://localhost:9001
website.mystore.https=https://localhost:9002`

in past , this was opening https://localhost:9002/powertools/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Measuring-%26-Layout-Tools/c/1358

but i want to go to https://localhost:9002/mystore/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Measuring-%26-Layout-Tools/c/1358

Comment: Also try to add "powertools.webroot=/powertools" to override the extension's webroot