# Cannot resolve value 'homepage' for attribute 'startingPage' (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I created a project with ant modulegen. b2b from b2c recipe, because hybris wiki says this.

But i could not get a proper result on `backoffice / wcms / website`

for that, mystore shows empty for

```
Name
```

and

```
Content Catalogs
```

I found that inpex that is not working on hac admin.

This is path

```
mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/stores/mystore/site.impex
```

This is the error:

> INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);siteMapConfig(&siteMapConfigId);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=mystoreContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=mystoreContentCatalog:Staged]);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=mystorePromoGrp]
>   ,8796093187112,,,column 12: could not resolve item for homepage| column 12: cannot resolve value 'homepage' for attribute 'startingPage';mystore;blue;B2C;mystore;mystoreContentCatalog;mystoreProductCatalog;en;mystoreSiteMapConfig;(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=mystore)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://mystore.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://api.hybrisdev.com(:[\d]+)?/rest/.*$,(?i)^https?://localhost(:[\d]+)?/rest/.*$;true;/?site=mystore;homepage;storefront,language;

error is for that line

```
>     # CMS Site
>     INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);siteMapConfig(&siteMapConfigId);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=$promoGrp]
>     ;$siteUid;blue;B2C;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;$storeUidSiteMapConfig;(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=$siteUid)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://$siteUid\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://api\.hybrisdev\.com(:[\d]+)?/rest/.*$,(?i)^https?://localhost(:[\d]+)?/rest/.*$;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;storefront,language
```

I followed the recipe wiki and

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094425

that wiki. What am i doing wrong?

```
    INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=PromoGrp];# unknown attributes [ContentPage.$contentCV] - cannot resolve item reference;# invalid item expression '# unknown attributes [ContentPage.$contentCV] - cannot resolve item reference' - unexpected expression at 45
,,,,unknown attributes [ContentPage.$contentCV] - cannot resolve item reference, invalid item expression '# unknown attributes [ContentPage.$contentCV] - cannot resolve item reference' - unexpected expression at 45;$siteUid;lambda;B2B;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=$siteUid)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://$siteUid\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;storefront,language,currency
```

Comment: The error is caused by the lack of a **ContentPage** instance named 'homepage' in the mentioned content catalogue. Make sure you create the content page as well before creating the CMSSite or use another existing content page

Comment: When i go to backoffice/wcms, i see that Content Catalogs part is selected with mystore.startpage was empty, i slected appareluk homepage but still can not import and i got error when i go to localhost:9002 : `

May 30, 2018 3:29:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.cms2.exceptions.CMSItemNotFoundExh root cause
de.hybris.platform.cms2.exceptions.CMSItemNotFoundException: No page with id [homepage] found`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your impex before importing CMS Site

```
INSERT_UPDATE SiteMapPage;&siteMapPage;code(code)[unique=true];frequency(code)[unique=true];priority[unique=true];active[default=true]
;Homepage;Homepage;daily;1.0;;
```

Comment: it already has this `INSERT_UPDATE SiteMapPage;&siteMapPage;code(code)[unique=true];frequency(code)[unique=true];priority[unique=true];active[default=true]
;Homepage;Homepage;daily;1.0;;
;Product;Product;weekly;0.6;;
;CategoryLanding;CategoryLanding;daily;0.9;;
;Category;Category;daily;0.8;;
;Store;Store;weekly;0.6;;
;Content;Content;monthly;0.4;;
;Custom;Custom;daily;1.0;;
`and importing it gives no problem

Comment: did you perform 'ant all' and updatesystem after successful import?

Comment: No because i already initialized and this was iniatialized in site.impex. After that i copied all impexes to import page to see which gives error and error is for site.impex `could not resolve item for homepage`. I did not try other impexes yet.

Comment: what is your hybris version?

Comment: i used that HYBRISCOMM6700P_0-80003492.ZIP

Comment: The basic problem you are facing here is due to the document you are following and the latest version of hybris you are using.the document is for 5+ versions and yours is 6.7. just have a look at the CoreDataImportService before initialization.the order in which impex files are imported set up there only.the chances of skipping some impex's which have dependency with the import failed(in your case) impex could be the problem here.

Comment: Actually i followed that mostly https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8acc8a5a86691014a20781b3f738213e.html 
After that finshed, i tried everything to make my store up, when i go to localhost:9002, ishould be able to see my store. So i also used that 5.7 version tutorial. I did not touch 'CoreDataImportService' . for example there is `store-responsive.impex` which is not in powertools but in electronics. but i want b2b

Comment: If you follow all 14 steps correctly in  help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8acc8a5a86691014a20781b3f738213e.html it should work.make sure you are using this link for store and you have added this in hosts file.https://powertools.local:9002/trainingstorefront/powertools/en/USD.

Comment: I dont want to use powertools. this link  works. I want to go to mystore store when i go to localhost. Should i copy all powertools files and rename them to mystore?

Answer (score 1):

I think some Impex might have failed during your system initialization. So what I would suggest.

- Since you have set up the custom extension with your store data, remove all OOTB stores(powertools, apparel-us etc.) from your localextension.xml file
- Initialize your system. Look for the error log in the console, note down all Impex which fail to load
- Correct those Impex and run it through hac Impex-Import
- Once setup correctly your store correctly, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362755/2478134) to access your site as root

Comment: I cant look on initialize be cause it takes at least 40 minutes on that old computer. Because of that,a fter initialize finishes, i copy all impexes to hac admin to see if all of them are succesful. In the question, that was not succesful. and i could not correct it. That is default impex which have come from ant module

Comment: As I said, make sure you have set up your custom extension correctly with all OOTB impex with your store data

Comment: But ant modulegen already created everything. should i copy impexes from powertools which is under `powertoolsi/resources/import/coredata` and rename?

Comment: It just create the template impex, if you want to have same OOTB site setup then you have to copy those. like WCMS components, pages, core data etc

Comment: From powertools? @HybrisFreelance

Comment: yeah if you are trying to setup b2b site

Answer (score -1):

You're using a version 6.7 of Hybris but you're following the wiki for the version 5.7.
Follow this [link](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c39af1286691014b2daed4f092998ca.html). [Here](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8958cae4b4d94912aa2a5a449352fb19.html) instead you can find the trails.